# Many To many relation and navigation property in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

Hi every one my question is about many to many relation in asp.net mvc5. Where i have a table `Users` and `Projects` they have many to many relation and both have each other in their navigation property. I want to fetch the Testers/Developers/Users(x) of those projects(y) which are added by MaanagerUser(a)

```
                    return View(db.Users.ToList().Where(u => u.Projects.Select().Where(s => s.Users.Contains(usr))));
```

`usr` is the Manager who added Many `projects` and i want to see the `testers` and `developers` of those projects

Following are the tables
`Users`
`+--------------------------------------+
|   UserId   |    UserName    |  Role   |
+---------------------------------------+
|    1       |   Drake        | Manager |
+---------------------------------------+
|    2       |   John         | Tester  |
+---------------------------------------+
|    3       |   Smith        |Developer|
+---------------------------------------+`
`Projects`
`+-----------------------------+
|   ProjectId  |  ProjectsName |
+------------------------------+
|       1      |    Project 1  |
+------------------------------+
|       2      |    Project 2  |
+------------------------------+`

`User_Projects`
`+-------------------------+
|   ProjectId  |  UserID   |
+--------------------------+
|       1      |     1     |
+--------------------------+
|       1      |     2     |
+--------------------------+
|       1      |     3     |
+--------------------------+
|       2      |     4     |
+--------------------------+
|       2      |     3     |
+--------------------------+`
Hope i explained my problem Thank You!

Comment: Does the table(s) have a CreatedByUser column to track who created it ?

Comment: No it is decided by user role which is manager, one project can have only one manager.

Comment: if i add a field in database created by in projects table then can u help me????  But it will violate the rule of many to many relation of User and project????